# Yelp API exception Handling Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on `Yelp API` through `gem 'yelp'` . Everything works fine but when we enter a location which is not provided by `yelp` it throws exception .

```
Yelp::Error::UnavailableForLocation
```

I have tried begin/end raise and rescue but not working . Can anyone tell , what's i'm doing wrong . here is what i tried

```
begin
 client = Yelp::client
 raise yelp_places_burst = client.search('lahore , pakistan')
end
rescue Exception => e
puts e.message
```

In addition , I want to send the error to js file (in response of ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a little bit confused on how an exception is rescued. The way to rescue an exception in Ruby is

```
begin
 # execution
rescue ErrorClass
 # do something
end
```

Therefore your code should  be

```
begin
  client = Yelp::client
  yelp_places_burst = client.search('lahore , pakistan')
rescue Yelp::Error::UnavailableForLocation => e
  puts e.message
end
```

Also note I replaced `Exception` with the specific exception class. In fact, it's not recommended to rescue `Exception` as it will hide several other very exceptional events.

Comment: Thanks but i think instead of `rescue` `puts e.message => e` , it should be `rescue Exception => e`

Comment: No, it should be `rescue Yelp::Error::UnavailableForLocation`. Sorry, I fixed the response. I used the wrong buffer when I pasted the class name.

Comment: can we return within the catch block  like `render` `json: { status: 'fail'}`

Comment: Yes, you can either return, return a value or set a variable.

Answer (score -1):

if you look at https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby/blob/develop/lib/yelp/error.rb you can see that Yelp::Error::UnavailableForLocation is extended from Base which extends StandardError. So you need to catch StandardError, not Exception.

You get some additional explanations here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception, which suggests you can use rescue => e which will catch StandardError by default.

Comment: `StandardError` inherits from `Exception`, that's not the problem. The problem with his code is that the error handling part is completely wrong. He used `raise` and the `rescue` statement is outside the block.